# Excel VBA run Macro automatically whenever a cell is changed from yes to no

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a simple way to get Excel to automatically execute a macro whenever a cell is changed?

```
Sub Change()
If Range("E94").Value = "no" Then
    Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E94").Value = "yes" Then
    Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

If someone changes the value in the cell E94 from "no" (standard) to "yes" there should "pop up" the cells from "95 - 118".
If I change back from "yes" to "no", they should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event, for the relevant sheet you want this code to run.

In your case, if you want to run this code only if cell "E94" is changed, then you need to check if that certain cell is changed, you do it with the line :

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E94")) Is Nothing Then
```

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E94")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "no" Then
        Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = "yes" Then
        Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. You saved my time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Worksheet_Change Event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Call your Sub here
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use the Target Range of the Event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False,False) = "E94" Then
    If Target.Value = "no" Then
        Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = "yes" Then
        Rows("95:118").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your code will hide/un-hide only row 94, and the OP wants to hide/un-hide rows("95:118")